# How to make products with no cost in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I want to create product catalog in wordpress using woocommerce, in that all products do not contain price but we can add products to cart and proceed to checkout i.e all products don't have any price but user can add to cart this is clients requirements. the process will be like

1. user will click on products add to cart button
2. he will add products and it's quantity to cart and then he will checkout from shop
3. admin will get a inquiry mail where mail contains all products that user added into cart so admin will contact user for next process

that is what clients want

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can hide price using CSS but it would be added in Cart. Or you should choose catalog mode to display products.

Comment: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', '__return_empty_string' );` Try this